# Trying to code a ANOVA One Way stats tests

Tags: python, statistics, anova

I have three columns that are as follows: column 1 : "sex"( data is female -or- male); column 2: "children" (0,1,2,3,4,5); and column 3: "bmi" (data floats).

I need to identify only the "female(s)" out column 1 but column 1 contains both sex (don't need the males). Associated with the females I need to get the number of children they have as either 0, 1 or 2 from column 2 and the column 3 BMI float for that particular female.

I need to create 3 new columns for results as follows:

child0       child1      child2

Row results are all females with columns above.

But the columns above should be filled with BMI float from column 3 and placed under the 3 columns for that female

Then I need to get the mean of all 3 columns and do an ANOVA -one way test with alpha=0.05 and say whether the mean BMI of women with 0, 1 or 2 children are the same or statistically different.

This is my code but stuck, AX5 is a modification to AX4 which I have added other information to earlier.

AX5=AX4

AX4['sex']=AX4['female'] and AX3['children']=AX3['0,1,2']

AX5['W_child_0','W_child_1', 'W_child_2']=pd.cut(x=AX5['sex'], bins=[0,1,2],labels=['yes 0', 'yes 1', 'yes 2'])

AX5

Data looks like this:

age  sex        bmi        children  smoker    region           charges

19   female  27.900         0        yes       southwest        16884.92400

18   male    33.770         1        no        southeast        1725.55230

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm a beginner so I've trie pd.cut and pandas-profilong for data, but since no clumns is grosses everyhting up. I 'm not good a pythin as I've only used for 1 month

Comment: I'm learning how to navigate stackoverflow at same time so a bit uncertain of a few things

Comment: Can I paste data into this comment area?

Comment: AX5=AX4
AX4['sex']=AX4['female'] and AX3['children']=AX3['0,1,2']
    

AX5['W_child_0','W_child_1', 'W_child_2']=pd.cut(x=AX5['sex'], bins=[0,1,2],labels=['yes 0', 'yes 1', 'yes 2']) 
AX5

Comment: AX4=AX3
AX4['IdealBMI']=pd.cut(x=AX4['bmi'], bins=[0,18.5,24.9, 55],labels=['Below BMI', 'Ideal BMI', 'Above BMI']) 
AX4

Comment: No, code and data should be edited to your question, not pasted into comments. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance on how to reformat your question and please update it accordingly.

Comment: Ugh, I'm going to be confused for awhile

Comment: I just don't know where to start with the code as it's identifying flot under BMI column and placing that float under the newly created child0, child1 and child2 columns for only the females from a mixed column of both sex. This dataframe manipulation is confusing to me just to get the right data into right places before trying stats.

Comment: It seems your intuition is to use Pandas to read in the dataset. That's great, focus on getting that prepared and then look to do the ANOVA test.